# For loop performance difference, and compiler optimization

Tags: c++, performance, gcc

---

I chose David's answer because he was the only one to present a solution to the difference in the for-loops with no optimization flags. The other answers demonstrate what happens when setting the optimization flags on.

---

Jerry Coffin's answer explained what happens when setting the optimization flags for this example. What remains unanswered is why superCalculationA runs slower than superCalculationB, when B performs one extra memory reference and one addition for each iteration. Nemo's post shows the assembler output. I confirmed this compiling with the `-S` flag on my PC, 2.9GHz Sandy Bridge (i5-2310), running Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit, as suggested by Matteo Italia.

---

I was experimenting with for-loops performance when I stumbled upon the following case.

I have the following code that does the same computation in two different ways.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdio>

using std::uint64_t;

uint64_t superCalculationA(int init, int end)
{
    uint64_t total = 0;
    for (int i = init; i < end; i++)
        total += i;
    return total;
}

uint64_t superCalculationB(int init, int todo)
{
    uint64_t total = 0;
    for (int i = init; i < init + todo; i++)
        total += i;
    return total;
}

int main()
{
    const uint64_t answer = 500000110500000000;

    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> start, end;
    double elapsed;

    std::printf("=====================================================\n");

    start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    uint64_t ret1 = superCalculationA(111, 1000000111);
    end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    elapsed = (end - start).count() * ((double) std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::period::num / std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::period::den);
    std::printf("Elapsed time: %.3f s | %.3f ms | %.3f us\n", elapsed, 1e+3*elapsed, 1e+6*elapsed);

    start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    uint64_t ret2 = superCalculationB(111, 1000000000);
    end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    elapsed = (end - start).count() * ((double) std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::period::num / std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::period::den);
    std::printf("Elapsed time: %.3f s | %.3f ms | %.3f us\n", elapsed, 1e+3*elapsed, 1e+6*elapsed);

    if (ret1 == answer)
    {
        std::printf("The first method, i.e. superCalculationA, succeeded.\n");
    }
    if (ret2 == answer)
    {
        std::printf("The second method, i.e. superCalculationB, succeeded.\n");
    }

    std::printf("=====================================================\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling this code with

> g++ main.cpp -o output --std=c++11

leads to the following result:

```
=====================================================
Elapsed time: 2.859 s | 2859.441 ms | 2859440.968 us
Elapsed time: 2.204 s | 2204.059 ms | 2204059.262 us
The first method, i.e. superCalculationA, succeeded.
The second method, i.e. superCalculationB, succeeded.
=====================================================
```

My first question is: **why is the second loop running 23% faster than the first?**

On the other hand, if I compile the code with

> g++ main.cpp -o output --std=c++11 -O1

The results improve a lot,

```
=====================================================
Elapsed time: 0.318 s | 317.773 ms | 317773.142 us
Elapsed time: 0.314 s | 314.429 ms | 314429.393 us
The first method, i.e. superCalculationA, succeeded.
The second method, i.e. superCalculationB, succeeded.
=====================================================
```

and the difference in time almost disappears.

But I could not believe my eyes when I set the -O2 flag,

> g++ main.cpp -o output --std=c++11 -O2

and got this:

```
=====================================================
Elapsed time: 0.000 s | 0.000 ms | 0.328 us
Elapsed time: 0.000 s | 0.000 ms | 0.208 us
The first method, i.e. superCalculationA, succeeded.
The second method, i.e. superCalculationB, succeeded.
=====================================================
```

So, my second question is: **What is the compiler doing when I set -O1 and -O2 flags that leads to this gigantic performance improvement?**

I checked [Optimized Option - Using the GNU Compiler Collection (GCC)](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html), but that did not clarify things.

---

By the way, I am compiling this code with g++ (GCC) 4.9.1.

---

**EDIT to confirm Basile Starynkevitch's assumption**

I edited the code, now `main` looks like this:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int start = atoi(argv[1]);
    int end   = atoi(argv[2]);
    int delta = end - start + 1;

    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> t_start, t_end;
    double elapsed;

    std::printf("=====================================================\n");

    t_start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    uint64_t ret1 = superCalculationB(start, delta);
    t_end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    elapsed = (t_end - t_start).count() * ((double) std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::period::num / std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::period::den);
    std::printf("Elapsed time: %.3f s | %.3f ms | %.3f us\n", elapsed, 1e+3*elapsed, 1e+6*elapsed);

    t_start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    uint64_t ret2 = superCalculationA(start, end);
    t_end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    elapsed = (t_end - t_start).count() * ((double) std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::period::num / std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::period::den);
    std::printf("Elapsed time: %.3f s | %.3f ms | %.3f us\n", elapsed, 1e+3*elapsed, 1e+6*elapsed);

    std::printf("Results were %s\n", (ret1 == ret2) ? "the same!" : "different!");
    std::printf("=====================================================\n");

    return 0;
}
```

These modifications really increased computation time, both for `-O1` and `-O2`. Both are giving me around 620 ms now. **Which proves that -O2 was really doing some computation at compile time**.

I still do not understand what these flags are doing to improve performance, and `-Ofast` does even better, at about 320ms.

Also notice that I have changed the order in which functions A and B are called to test Jerry Coffin's assumption. Compiling this code with no optimizer flags still gives me around 2.2 secs in B and 2.8 secs in A. So I figure that it is not a cache thing. Just reinforcing that I am **not** talking about optimization in the first case (the one with no flags), I just want to know what makes the seconds loop run faster than the first.

Comment: Run `g++` with `-S` and check the assembly.

Comment: Without optimizations turned on (your first case), it doesn't make sense to compare timings because the generated code is very nearly a direct translation of your code to assembly. With optimizations on, the compiler can almost certainly eliminate your loop entirely in this case.

Comment: I guess that with `-O2` GCC is doing most computations at compile time. The arguments to `SuperCalculationA` & `SuperCalculationB` should be variable, e.g. given thru the program arguments (e.g. `int init = atoi(argv[1]); int end = atoi(argv[2]);` in your `main`)

Comment: I must correct myself: looking at the assembly at `-O0` doesn't illuminate the issue a tiny bit. The emitted assembly is obviously a naive C->assembly translation, but, despite doing *more* things in very similar code (and accessing one more location on the stack) it turns out that `superCalculationB` is faster (confirmed by the profiler). The result holds even repeating both calculations several times in a `for` loop.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: Yeah, I would like to understand what is going on in the unoptimized case. The assembly for the second routine certainly looks like it should be slower, which means I don't understand the CPU well enough. Anyone know how to contact Mysticial?

Comment: @MatteoItalia I am trying understand the assembly, but I have not studied a lot on this subject yet, so I can't really tell much from it.

Comment: I know how to contact Mysticial, but he follows the performance tag pretty closely, so if he was interested he'd probably have commented already.

Comment: @jcmonteiro Thanks for selecting my answer. I did some more homework and now think I have a more solid explanation without any mysteries. Please check out my revised answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: After learning more about dependencies in processor pipelining, I revised my answer, removing some unnecessary details and offering a more concrete explanation of the slowdown.

---

It appears that the performance difference in the -O0 case is due to processor pipelining.

First, the assembly (for the -O0 build), copied from Nemo's answer, with some of my own comments inline:

```
superCalculationA(int, int):
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    movl    %edi, -20(%rbp)    # init
    movl    %esi, -24(%rbp)    # end
    movq    $0, -8(%rbp)       # total = 0
    movl    -20(%rbp), %eax    # copy init to register rax
    movl    %eax, -12(%rbp)    # i = [rax]
    jmp .L7
.L8:
    movl    -12(%rbp), %eax    # copy i to register rax
    cltq
    addq    %rax, -8(%rbp)     # total += [rax]
    addl    $1, -12(%rbp)      # i++
.L7:
    movl    -12(%rbp), %eax    # copy i to register rax
    cmpl    -24(%rbp), %eax    # [rax] < end
    jl  .L8
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    popq    %rbp
    ret

superCalculationB(int, int):
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    movl    %edi, -20(%rbp)    # init
    movl    %esi, -24(%rbp)    # todo
    movq    $0, -8(%rbp)       # total = 0
    movl    -20(%rbp), %eax    # copy init to register rax
    movl    %eax, -12(%rbp)    # i = [rax]
    jmp .L11
.L12:
    movl    -12(%rbp), %eax    # copy i to register rax
    cltq
    addq    %rax, -8(%rbp)     # total += [rax]
    addl    $1, -12(%rbp)      # i++
.L11:
    movl    -20(%rbp), %edx    # copy init to register rdx
    movl    -24(%rbp), %eax    # copy todo to register rax
    addl    %edx, %eax         # [rax] += [rdx]  (so [rax] = init+todo)
    cmpl    -12(%rbp), %eax    # i < [rax]
    jg  .L12
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    popq    %rbp
    ret
```

---

In both functions, the stack layout looks like this:

```
Addr Content

24   end/todo
20   init
16   <empty>
12   i
08   total
04   
00   <base pointer>
```

(Note that `total` is a 64-bit int and so occupies two 4-byte slots.)

These are the key lines of `superCalculationA()`:

```
    addl    $1, -12(%rbp)      # i++
.L7:
    movl    -12(%rbp), %eax    # copy i to register rax
    cmpl    -24(%rbp), %eax    # [rax] < end
```

The stack address `-12(%rbp)` (which holds the value of `i`) is written to in the `addl` instruction, and then it is immediately read in the very next instruction. The read instruction cannot begin until the write has completed. This represents a block in the pipeline, causing `superCalculationA()` to be slower than `superCalculationB()`.

You might be curious why `superCalculationB()` doesn't have this same pipeline block. It's really just an artifact of how gcc compiles the code in -O0 and doesn't represent anything fundamentally interesting. Basically, in `superCalculationA()`, the comparison `i<end` is performed by reading `i` from a **register**, while in `superCalculationB()`, the comparison `i<init+todo` is performed by reading `i` from the **stack**.

To demonstrate that this is just an artifact, let's replace

```
for (int i = init; i < end; i++)
```

with

```
for (int i = init; end > i; i++)
```

in `superCalculateA()`. The generated assembly then looks the same, with just the following change to the key lines:

```
    addl    $1, -12(%rbp)      # i++
.L7:
    movl    -24(%rbp), %eax    # copy end to register rax
    cmpl    -12(%rbp), %eax    # i < [rax]
```

Now `i` is read from the stack, and the pipeline block is gone. Here are the performance numbers after making this change:

```
=====================================================
Elapsed time: 2.296 s | 2295.812 ms | 2295812.000 us
Elapsed time: 2.368 s | 2367.634 ms | 2367634.000 us
The first method, i.e. superCalculationA, succeeded.
The second method, i.e. superCalculationB, succeeded.
=====================================================
```

It should be noted that this is really a toy example, since we are compiling with -O0. In the real world, we compile with -O2 or -O3. In that case, the compiler orders the instructions in such a way so as to minimize pipeline blocks, and we don't need to worry about whether to write `i<end` or `end>i`.

Answer (score 11):

My immediate guess would be that the second is faster, not because of the changes you made to the loop, but because it's second, so the cache is already primed when it runs.

To test the theory, I re-arranged your code to reverse the order in which the two calculations were called:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdio>

using std::uint64_t;

uint64_t superCalculationA(int init, int end)
{
    uint64_t total = 0;
    for (int i = init; i < end; i++)
        total += i;
    return total;
}

uint64_t superCalculationB(int init, int todo)
{
    uint64_t total = 0;
    for (int i = init; i < init + todo; i++)
        total += i;
    return total;
}

int main()
{
    const uint64_t answer = 500000110500000000;

    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> start, end;
    double elapsed;

    std::printf("=====================================================\n");

    start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    uint64_t ret2 = superCalculationB(111, 1000000000);
    end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    elapsed = (end - start).count() * ((double) std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::period::num / std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::period::den);
    std::printf("Elapsed time: %.3f s | %.3f ms | %.3f us\n", elapsed, 1e+3*elapsed, 1e+6*elapsed);

    start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    uint64_t ret1 = superCalculationA(111, 1000000111);
    end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    elapsed = (end - start).count() * ((double) std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::period::num / std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::period::den);
    std::printf("Elapsed time: %.3f s | %.3f ms | %.3f us\n", elapsed, 1e+3*elapsed, 1e+6*elapsed);

    if (ret1 == answer)
    {
        std::printf("The first method, i.e. superCalculationA, succeeded.\n");
    }
    if (ret2 == answer)
    {
        std::printf("The second method, i.e. superCalculationB, succeeded.\n");
    }

    std::printf("=====================================================\n");

    return 0;
}
```

The result I got was:

```
=====================================================
Elapsed time: 0.286 s | 286.000 ms | 286000.000 us
Elapsed time: 0.271 s | 271.000 ms | 271000.000 us
The first method, i.e. superCalculationA, succeeded.
The second method, i.e. superCalculationB, succeeded.
=====================================================
```

So, when version A runs first, it's slower. When version B run's first, it's slower.

To confirm, I added an extra call to `superCalculationB` before doing the timing on either version A or B. After that, I tried running the program three times. For those three runs, I'd judge the results a tie (version A was faster once and version B was faster twice, but neither won dependably nor by a wide enough margin to be meaningful).

That doesn't prove that it's actually a cache situation as such, but does give a pretty strong indication that it's a matter of the order in which the functions are called, not the difference in the code itself.

As far as what the compiler does to make the code faster: the main thing it does is unroll a few iterations of the loop. We can get pretty much the same effect if we unroll a few iterations by hand:

```
uint64_t superCalculationC(int init, int end)
{
    int f_end = end - ((end - init) & 7);

    int i;
    uint64_t total = 0;
    for (i = init; i < f_end; i += 8) {
        total += i;
        total += i + 1;
        total += i + 2;
        total += i + 3;
        total += i + 4;
        total += i + 5;
        total += i + 6;
        total += i + 7;
    }

    for (; i < end; i++)
        total += i;

    return total;
}
```

This has a property that some might find rather odd: it's actually faster when compiled with -O2 than with -O3. When compiled with -O2, it's also about five times faster than either of the other two are when compiled with -O3.

The primary reason for the ~5x speed gain compared to the compiler's loop unrolling is that we've unrolled the loop somewhat differently (and more intelligently, IMO) than the compiler does. We compute `f_end` to tell us how many times the unrolled loop should execute. We execute those iterations, *then* we execute a separate loop to "clean up" any odd iterations at the end.

The compiler instead generates code that's roughly equivalent to something like this:

```
for (i = init; i < end; i += 8) {
    total += i;
    if (i + 1 >= end) break;
    total += i + 1;
    if (i + 2 >= end) break;
    total += i + 2;
    // ...
}
```

Although this is quite a bit faster than when the loop hasn't been unrolled at all, it's quite a bit faster still to eliminate those extra checks from the main loop, and execute a separate loop for any odd iterations.

Given such a trivial loop body being executed such a large number of times, you can also improve speed (when compiled with -O2) still further by unrolling more iterations of the loop. With 16 iterations unrolled, it was about twice as fast as the code above with 8 iterations unrolled:

```
uint64_t superCalculationC(int init, int end)
{
    int first_end = end - ((end - init) & 0xf);

    int i;
    uint64_t total = 0;
    for (i = init; i < first_end; i += 16) {
        total += i + 0;
        total += i + 1;
        total += i + 2;

        // code for `i+3` through `i+13` goes here

        total += i + 14;
        total += i + 15;
    }

    for (; i < end; i++)
        total += i;

    return total;
}
```

I haven't tried to explore the limit of gains from unrolling this particular loop, but unrolling 32 iterations nearly doubles the speed again. Depending on the processor you're using, you *might* get some small gains by unrolling 64 iterations, but I'd guess we're starting to approach the limits--at some point, performance gains will probably level off, then (if you unroll still more iterations) probably drop off, quite possibly dramatically.

Summary: with `-O3` the compiler unrolls a number of iterations of the loop. This is extremely effective in this case, primarily because we have *many* executions of nearly the most trivial possible loop body. Unrolling the loop by hand is even more effective than letting the compiler do it--we can unroll more intelligently, and we can simply unroll more iterations than the compiler does. The extra intelligence can give us an improvement of around 5:1, and the extra iterations another 4:1 or so<sup>1</sup> (at the expense of somewhat longer, slightly less readable code).

Final caveat: as always with optimization, your mileage may vary. Differences in compilers and/or processors mean you're likely to get at least somewhat different results than I did. I'd expect my hand-unrolled loop to be substantially faster than the other two in most cases, but exactly how much faster is likely to vary.

---

<sup>1. But note that this is comparing the hand-unrolled loop with -O2 to the original loop with -O3. When compiled with -O3, the hand-unrolled loop runs much more slowly.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Jerry. Are you compiling this code with some optimizer flag? I double checked my code, and compiling with no -O0 flag gives me those results, 2.8 for A and 2.2 for B, even when I change the order of the calls.

Comment: Yes, I tried it with -O2 and -O3 (and also with MS VC++, using -O2b2 -GL). Different total time, but same basic results with both compilers: whichever routine ran first, also ran slower).

Comment: When compiling with these flags they really give the same results. My point is that when compiling without them routine B runs faster than A. Try removing all optimizer flags.

Comment: Looking at optimization with optimization disabled is about the most pointless exercise humanly possible. Just for grins I did compile to assembly with both -O2 and -O3. In both cases, the compiler created *identical* code for the two versions of the code. Any difference in execution speed is *purely* an artifact of how you're doing the timing.

Comment: I think you did not understand the question. I asked what caused the difference in time with optimization disabled and what optimization did to reduce the computation time.

Comment: @jcmonteiro: I've added a bit about the primary optimization involved, at least when moving from -O2 to -O3.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60298/discussion-between-jcmonteiro-and-jerry-coffin).

Comment: Which cache do you mean, exactly? There is almost no memory footprint here at all. (Talking about the unoptimized case. The -O2/-O3 behavior is relatively uninteresting.) Hard to argue with your empirical results, but I still do not (yet) see an explanation for them.

Comment: @Nemo: It's true that memory usage is minimal. Another possibility is the time taken to sense that the CPU is busy before increasing the clock speed.

Comment: Interesting idea, so I tried disabling TurboBoost and related clock-scaling mechanisms and pinned my clock speed to 2.9GHz. For me, `superCalculationA` is now 3120ms and `superCalculationB` is 2437ms, and it _does not matter what order I run them_ or if I run them several times etc. I don't think we even have the start of an explanation here...

Comment: @Nemo: Seems a bit odd--with the implementations in the question, I quite consistently (on a couple different machines) get the first one to run going slower, and if I do a dry run before timing, neither is consistently faster than the other.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: I have put my own observations in an answer that is not really an answer. I have tried this six ways to Sunday, and I swear I always get the same (divergent) speeds for the loops. What model(s) of CPU have you tried?

Comment: My CPU here at home is a cheap AMD (A6-6400K). Yesterday I ran it at work on a Xeon (don't remember exact model #).

Comment: "you might get some small gains by unrolling 64 iterations, but I'd guess we're starting to approach the limits" - I'd expect all the +='s are being optimised into one `+=` for `n*i + c` (can you see that in the -S output?) which wouldn't degrade with further unrolling, but eventually at the extreme you risk more iterations in the "clean up" loop.

Comment: Looking at the assembly, it is clear that with -O2 the functions do not even get called. Surt has the correct explanation.

Comment: @David: His results pretty clearly don't agree with what I'm seeing. Seems unlikely that it's the compiler difference (4.9.0 vs. 4.9.1), but I'm not sure what flags may be different.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I'm using 4.7.2, and my assembly looks like his. My assembly contains hard-coded constants like 2696277389 and 1051772663, which seem to be intermediate values generated by inlining the computation. When I pass in the constant values by command line instead of hard-coding in main(), I get the same approximate runtime of ~600ms.

Comment: @David: If we assume that's correct, we're left with 2 even greater conundrums: 1) how would my changing the code in a function that isn't called change the speed so drastically, and 2) how is it managing to take even close to a microsecond (not to mention multiple milliseconds) to execute the code he showed? The code he shows should execute within a few nanoseconds or so (at most).

Comment: @jerrycoffin My code executes in under 1 microsecond with -O2, as does the OP's. I don't see anything in Surt's answer that suggests that his code takes any longer. I'm not sure of the reason, but it seems that the compilers used by myself, the OP, and Surt, are behaving differently from the one you are using.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Also, I'm noticing that both the OP and I clock the -O0 calls at >2sec, while your -O0 is taking <0.3sec. This again suggests that your compiler is behaving differently from ours. The fact that his -O1 calls clock in at around 0.3sec makes me guess that your compiler's -O0 somehow behaves like OP's -O1.

Answer (score 6):

Checking the assembly output is really the only way to illuminate such things.

Compiler optimisations will do a great deal of things, including things that are not strictly "standard compliant" (although, that is not the case with `-O1` and `-O2`, to my knowledge) - for instance check, `-Ofast` switch.

I have found this helpful: http://gcc.godbolt.org/, and with your demo code [here](http://goo.gl/sr6ztX)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Rusan. Nice website, I will certainly use it in the future. As far as assembly goes I am still learning, so if your could point out what is happening when I turn the flags -O1 and -Ofast I would appreciate. Please refer to the edited main function where I added argc and argv.

Answer (score 5):

### -O2

Explaining the -O2 result is easy, looking at the code from [godbolt](http://goo.gl/sr6ztX) change to -O2

```
main:
pushq   %rbx
movl    $.LC2, %edi
call    puts
call    std::chrono::_V2::system_clock::now()
movq    %rax, %rbx
call    std::chrono::_V2::system_clock::now()
pxor    %xmm0, %xmm0
subq    %rbx, %rax
movsd   .LC4(%rip), %xmm2
movl    $.LC6, %edi
movsd   .LC5(%rip), %xmm1
cvtsi2sdq   %rax, %xmm0
movl    $3, %eax
mulsd   .LC3(%rip), %xmm0
mulsd   %xmm0, %xmm2
mulsd   %xmm0, %xmm1
call    printf
call    std::chrono::_V2::system_clock::now()
movq    %rax, %rbx
call    std::chrono::_V2::system_clock::now()
pxor    %xmm0, %xmm0
subq    %rbx, %rax
movsd   .LC4(%rip), %xmm2
movl    $.LC6, %edi
movsd   .LC5(%rip), %xmm1
cvtsi2sdq   %rax, %xmm0
movl    $3, %eax
mulsd   .LC3(%rip), %xmm0
mulsd   %xmm0, %xmm2
mulsd   %xmm0, %xmm1
call    printf
movl    $.LC7, %edi
call    puts
movl    $.LC8, %edi
call    puts
movl    $.LC2, %edi
call    puts
xorl    %eax, %eax
popq    %rbx
ret
```

There is no call to the 2 functions, further there is no compare of the results.

Now why can that be? its of course the power of optimization, the program is too simple ...

First the power of inlining is applied, after which the compiler can see that all the parameters are in fact literal values (111, 1000000111, 1000000000, 500000110500000000) and therefore constants.

It finds out that init + todo is a loop invariant and replace them with end, defining end before the loop from B as end = init + todo = 111 + 1000000000 = 1000000111

Both loops are now known to be containing only compile time values. They are further completely the same:

```
uint64_t total = 0;
for (int i = 111; i < 1000000111; i++)
    total += i;
return total;
```

The compiler sees it is a summation, total is the accumulator, it is an equal stride 1 sum so the compiler makes the ultimate loop unrolling, namely all, but it knows that this form has the sum of

Rewriting Gauss's formel s=n*(n+1)

```
111+1000000110
110+1000000109
...
1000000109+110
1000000110+111=1000000221
```

loops = 1000000111-111 = 1E9

half it as we got the double of the looked for

1000000221 * 1E9 / 2 = 500000110500000000

which is the result looked for 500000110500000000

Now that is has the result which is a compile time constant it can compare it with the wanted result and note it is *always* true so it can remove it.

The time noted is the minimum time for system_clock on your PC.

### -O0

The timing of the -O0 is more difficult and most likely is an artifact of the missing align for functions and jumps, both µops cache and loopbuffer likes alignment of 32 bytes. You can test that if you add some

```
asm("nop");
```

in front of A's loop, 2-3 might do the trick.
Storeforwards also like that their values are naturally aligned.

Comment: This should be the top answer for the -O2 case.

Answer (score 2):

(This is not exactly an answer, but it does include more data, including some that conflicts with Jerry Coffin's.)

The interesting question is why the unoptimized routines perform so differently and counter-intuitively. The `-O2` and `-O3` cases are relatively simple to explain, and others have done so.

For completeness, [here is the assembly](http://goo.gl/sr6ztX) (thanks @Rutan Kax) for `superCalculationA` and `superCalculationB` produced by GCC 4.9.1:

```
superCalculationA(int, int):
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    movl    %edi, -20(%rbp)
    movl    %esi, -24(%rbp)
    movq    $0, -8(%rbp)
    movl    -20(%rbp), %eax
    movl    %eax, -12(%rbp)
    jmp .L7
.L8:
    movl    -12(%rbp), %eax
    cltq
    addq    %rax, -8(%rbp)
    addl    $1, -12(%rbp)
.L7:
    movl    -12(%rbp), %eax
    cmpl    -24(%rbp), %eax
    jl  .L8
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    popq    %rbp
    ret

superCalculationB(int, int):
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    movl    %edi, -20(%rbp)
    movl    %esi, -24(%rbp)
    movq    $0, -8(%rbp)
    movl    -20(%rbp), %eax
    movl    %eax, -12(%rbp)
    jmp .L11
.L12:
    movl    -12(%rbp), %eax
    cltq
    addq    %rax, -8(%rbp)
    addl    $1, -12(%rbp)
.L11:
    movl    -20(%rbp), %edx
    movl    -24(%rbp), %eax
    addl    %edx, %eax
    cmpl    -12(%rbp), %eax
    jg  .L12
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    popq    %rbp
    ret
```

It sure looks to me like B is doing more work.

My test platform is a 2.9GHz Sandy Bridge EP processor (E5-2690) running Red Hat Enterprise 6 Update 3. My compiler is GCC 4.9.1 and produces the assembly above.

To make sure Turbo Boost and related CPU-frequency-diddling technologies are not interfering with the measurement, I ran:

```
pkill cpuspeed # if you have it running
grep MHz /proc/cpuinfo # to see where you start
modprobe acpi_cpufreq # if you do not have it loaded
cd /sys/devices/system/cpu 
for cpuN in cpu[0-9]* ; do
    echo userspace > $cpuN/cpufreq/scaling_governor
    echo 2000000 > $cpuN/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed
done
grep MHz /proc/cpuinfo # to see if it worked
```

This pins the CPU frequency to 2.0 GHz and disables Turbo Boost.

Jerry observed these two routines running faster or slower depending on the order in which he executed them. *I could not reproduce that result.* For me, `superCalculationB` consistently runs 25-30% faster than `superCalculationA`, regardless of the Turbo Boost or clock speed settings. That includes running them multiple times in arbitrary order. For example, at 2.0GHz `superCalculationA` consistently takes a little over 4500ms and `superCalculationB` consistently takes at little under 3600ms.

I have yet to see any theory that even begins to explain this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Nemo. I am also using GCC 4.9.1 and it produces the same assembly as yours did. I am wandering throught this assembly output to see if I can find what is going on. For me it seems that superCalculationB is doing more work too.

Comment: B is doing one load and one addition that A isn't. That gives 6 memory references instead of 5, and most of the reason this is so much slower than with -O2 (for example) is due to the constant reference to memory instead of holding values in registers. Hard to see how 20% more memory references (or 17%, depending on viewpoint) could lead to a 25% speed difference though.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Also B is 25% _faster_ than A. So 20% more memory references is resulting in a 25% _increase_ in speed. Store forwarding does mean a memory reference isn't always a memory reference... But still, I have no idea what is going on here.

Answer (score 2):

**Processors are complicated**. Execution time depends on many things, many of which are outside your control. Just a few possibilities:

a. Your computer probably doesn't have a constant clock speed. It could be that the clock speed is usually set rather low to avoid wasting energy / battery life / producing excessive heat. When your program starts running, the OS figures out that power is needed and increases the clock speed. To verify, change the order of the calls - if the second loop executed is always faster than the first one, that may be the reason.

b. The exact execution speed, especially for a tight loop like yours, depends on how instructions are aligned in memory. Some processors may run a loop faster if it is completely contained within one cache line instead of two, or in two cache lines instead of three. Some compilers will add nop instructions to align loops on cache lines to optimise for this, most don't. Quite possible that one of the loops was aligned better by pure luck and therefore runs faster.

c. The exact execution speed may depend on the exact order in which instructions are dispatched. Slightly different code may run at different speeds due to subtle differences in the code which may be processor dependent, and anyway may be hard for the compiler to consider.

d. There is some evidence that Intel processors may have problems with artificially short loops which may happen only with artificial benchmarks. Your code is quite close to "artificial". There have been cases discussed in other threads where very short loops ran unexpectedly slow, and adding instructions made them run faster.

Comment: I increased the number of instructions inside both loops and A gradually became faster than B. I think the possibility you presented in "d." was the answer. Could you present further information regarding this subject so I can accept your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Answer of first question:

1. It makes faster after doing it once for for loops but i am not sure just commenting according to my experiment results.(experiment 1 change their names(B->A,A->B) experiment 2 run one function has for loop before time checks,experiment 3 start one for loop before time checks)
2. First programs should work faster the reason is second function is does 2 operation when first function does 1 operation.

I leave here updated code which explain my answer.

Answer of second question:

I am not sure but there can be two ways coming my mind,

It can be formalize your function in some way and get rid of loops because the difference can be destroyed by that way(like "return end-init" or "return todo" I don't know, I'm not sure)

It has -fauto_inc_dec and it can make that difference because these functions all about increments and decrements.

I hope it can help.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdio>

using std::uint64_t;

uint64_t superCalculationA(int init, int end)
{
    uint64_t total = 0;
    for (int i = init; i < end; i++)
        total += i;
    return total;
}
uint64_t superCalculationB(int init, int todo)
{
    uint64_t total = 0;
    for (int i = init; i < init+todo; i++)
        total += i;
    return total;
}
int add(int a1,int a2){printf("multiple times added\n");return a1+a2;}
uint64_t superCalculationC(int init, int todo)
{
    uint64_t total = 0;
    for (int i = init; i < add(init , todo); i++)
        total += i;
    return total;
}

int main()
{
    const uint64_t answer = 500000110500000000;

    std::clock_t start=clock();
    double elapsed;

    std::printf("=====================================================\n");

    superCalculationA(111, 1000000111);

    start = clock();
    uint64_t ret1 = superCalculationA(111, 1000000111);
    elapsed = ((std::clock()-start)*1.0/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    std::printf("Elapsed time: %.3f s | %.3f ms | %.3f us\n", elapsed, 1e+3*elapsed,    1e+6*elapsed);

    start = clock();
    uint64_t ret2 = superCalculationB(111, 1000000000);
    elapsed = ((std::clock()-start)*1.0/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    std::printf("Elapsed time: %.3f s | %.3f ms | %.3f us\n", elapsed, 1e+3*elapsed, 1e+6*elapsed);

    if (ret1 == answer)
    {
        std::printf("The first method, i.e. superCalculationA, succeeded.\n");
    }
    if (ret2 == answer)
    {
        std::printf("The second method, i.e. superCalculationB, succeeded.\n");
    }

    std::printf("=====================================================\n");

    return 0;
}
```