# SSE Intrinsics and loop unrolling

Tags: c++, optimization, sse, loop-unrolling

I am attempting to optimise some loops and I have managed but I wonder if I have only done it partially correct. Say for example that I have this loop:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
b[i] = a[i]*2;
}
```

unrolling this by a factor of 3, produces this:

```
int unroll = (n/4)*4;
for(i=0;i<unroll;i+=4)
{
b[i] = a[i]*2;
b[i+1] = a[i+1]*2;
b[i+2] = a[i+2]*2;
b[i+3] = a[i+3]*2;
}
for(;i<n;i++)
{
b[i] = a[i]*2;
}
```

Now is the SSE translation equivalent:

```
__m128 ai_v = _mm_loadu_ps(&a[i]);
__m128 two_v = _mm_set1_ps(2);
__m128 ai2_v = _mm_mul_ps(ai_v, two_v);
_mm_storeu_ps(&b[i], ai2_v);
```

or is it:

```
__m128 ai_v = _mm_loadu_ps(&a[i]);
__m128 two_v = _mm_set1_ps(2);
__m128 ai2_v = _mm_mul_ps(ai_v, two_v);
_mm_storeu_ps(&b[i], ai2_v);

__m128 ai1_v = _mm_loadu_ps(&a[i+1]);
__m128 two1_v = _mm_set1_ps(2);
__m128 ai_1_2_v = _mm_mul_ps(ai1_v, two1_v);
_mm_storeu_ps(&b[i+1], ai_1_2_v);

__m128 ai2_v = _mm_loadu_ps(&a[i+2]);
__m128 two2_v = _mm_set1_ps(2);
__m128 ai_2_2_v = _mm_mul_ps(ai2_v, two2_v);
_mm_storeu_ps(&b[i+2], ai_2_2_v);

__m128 ai3_v = _mm_loadu_ps(&a[i+3]);
__m128 two3_v = _mm_set1_ps(2);
__m128 ai_3_2_v = _mm_mul_ps(ai3_v, two3_v);
_mm_storeu_ps(&b[i+3], ai_3_2_v);
```

I am slightly confused about the section of code:

```
for(;i<n;i++)
{
b[i] = a[i]*2;
}
```

what does this do? Is it just to do the extra parts for example if the loop is not dividable by the factor you choose to unroll it by? Thank you.

Comment: The last section you ask about does in fact deal with the remainder. If n is an integer then `n/4` will discard the remainder. So `for(;i<n;i++)` does the last bit.

Comment: Ok thank you for clearing that part up for me. Much appreciated, that's what I thought it did.

Comment: I assume that you have already checked the resulting object code and verified that *your compiler does not already do this for you*, even with the appropriate flags? No point in trying to outsmart the optimizer.

Comment: You might like having a look at [Boost.SIMD](https://meetingcpp.com/tl_files/mcpp/slides/12/simd.pdf), it looks very neat.

Comment: why do you use `_mm_mul_ps` to multiply by 2? Why don't use `_mm_sll_epi32` or just a single `_mm_add_ps(ai_v, ai_v)`? No separate `two2_v` is needed

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: Good point, but I think you mean `_mm_add_ps`, not `ss`.  Also, an integer shift won't give the desired result on FP data.

Comment: im limited to sse3, are these instructions available in sse3? Also when runing the prolog section of code I get, "tets.c:69:12: error: ‘i’ undeclared (first use in this function)
      }for(;i<N;i++){"

Comment: As usual, ill-advised attempt at manual optimization. Just tried your test with gcc in optimization mode. Of course, the loops were unrolled and SSE-specific instructions were used.

Comment: @SergeyA: Yes, on MSVC it also proves to be ill-advised in this case, but I was surprised to see that SSE instructions were not used, and was much faster without them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is the first block:

```
    __m128 ai_v = _mm_loadu_ps(&a[i]);
    __m128 two_v = _mm_set1_ps(2);
    __m128 ai2_v = _mm_mul_ps(ai_v,two_v);
    _mm_storeu_ps(&b[i],ai2_v);
```

It already takes four variables at a time.

Here is the full program with the equivalent section of code commented out:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int i{0};
    float a[10] ={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    float b[10] ={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

    int n = 10;
    int unroll = (n/4)*4;
    for (i=0; i<unroll; i+=4) {
        //b[i] = a[i]*2;
        //b[i+1] = a[i+1]*2;
        //b[i+2] = a[i+2]*2;
        //b[i+3] = a[i+3]*2;
        __m128 ai_v = _mm_loadu_ps(&a[i]);
        __m128 two_v = _mm_set1_ps(2);
        __m128 ai2_v = _mm_mul_ps(ai_v,two_v);
        _mm_storeu_ps(&b[i],ai2_v);
    }

    for (; i<n; i++) {
        b[i] = a[i]*2;
    }

    for (auto i : a) { std::cout << i << "\t"; }
    std::cout << "\n";
    for (auto i : b) { std::cout << i << "\t"; }
    std::cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

As for efficiency; it seems that the assembly on my system generates `movups` instructions, whereas the hand rolled code could be made to use `movaps` which should be faster.

I used the following program to do some benchmarks:

```
#include <iostream>
//#define NO_UNROLL
//#define UNROLL
//#define SSE_UNROLL
#define SSE_UNROLL_ALIGNED

int main()
{
    const size_t array_size = 100003;
#ifdef SSE_UNROLL_ALIGNED
    __declspec(align(16)) int i{0};
    __declspec(align(16)) float a[array_size] ={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    __declspec(align(16)) float b[array_size] ={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
#endif
#ifndef SSE_UNROLL_ALIGNED
    int i{0};
    float a[array_size] ={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    float b[array_size] ={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
#endif

    int n = array_size;
    int unroll = (n/4)*4;


    for (size_t j{0}; j < 100000; ++j) {
#ifdef NO_UNROLL
        for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
            b[i] = a[i]*2;
        }
#endif
#ifdef UNROLL
        for (i=0; i<unroll; i+=4) {
            b[i] = a[i]*2;
            b[i+1] = a[i+1]*2;
            b[i+2] = a[i+2]*2;
            b[i+3] = a[i+3]*2;
        }
#endif
#ifdef SSE_UNROLL
        for (i=0; i<unroll; i+=4) {
            __m128 ai_v = _mm_loadu_ps(&a[i]);
            __m128 two_v = _mm_set1_ps(2);
            __m128 ai2_v = _mm_mul_ps(ai_v,two_v);
            _mm_storeu_ps(&b[i],ai2_v);
        }
#endif
#ifdef SSE_UNROLL_ALIGNED
        for (i=0; i<unroll; i+=4) {
            __m128 ai_v = _mm_load_ps(&a[i]);
            __m128 two_v = _mm_set1_ps(2);
            __m128 ai2_v = _mm_mul_ps(ai_v,two_v);
            _mm_store_ps(&b[i],ai2_v);
        }
#endif
#ifndef NO_UNROLL
        for (; i<n; i++) {
            b[i] = a[i]*2;
        }
#endif
    }

    //for (auto i : a) { std::cout << i << "\t"; }
    //std::cout << "\n";
    //for (auto i : b) { std::cout << i << "\t"; }
    //std::cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

I got the following results (x86):

- `NO_UNROLL`:      **0.994** seconds, no SSE chosen by compiler
- `UNROLL`:         **3.511** seconds, uses `movups`
- `SSE_UNROLL`:     **3.315** seconds, uses `movups`
- `SSE_UNROLL_ALIGNED`: **3.276** seconds, uses `movaps`

So it is clear that unrolling the loop has not helped in this case. Even ensuring that we use the more efficient `movaps` doesn't help much.

But I got an even stranger result when compiling to 64 bit (x64):

- `NO_UNROLL`:     **1.138** seconds, no SSE chosen by compiler
- `UNROLL`:            **1.409** seconds, no SSE chosen by compiler
- `SSE_UNROLL`:        **1.420** seconds, **still no SSE chosen by compiler!**
- `SSE_UNROLL_ALIGNED`:    **1.476** seconds, **still no SSE chosen by compiler!**

It seems MSVC sees through the proposal and generates better assembly regardless, albeit still slower than had we not tried any hand optimization at all.

Comment: Recently, Peter Cordes educated me on the fact that you pay no penalty when using MOVUPS for aligned data. That is probably why the compiler uses it, because it is more general. There's no compelling reason to emit MOVAPS except perhaps when tuning for some very old architectures. To be clear, unaligned data accesses are still penalized, though, so make sure that you align the data if you want it to be as fast as possible. This can be done either by intrinsics or by compiler hints/attributes

Comment: Anyway, +1 to you as well for actually benchmarking it. This is the real lesson that Kieran should take away from these answers.

Answer (score 2):

As usual, it is not efficient to unroll loops and try to match SSE instructions manually. Compilers can do it better than you. For example, the provided sample is compiled into SSE-enabled ASM automatically:

```
foo:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    testl   %edi, %edi
    jle .L7
    movl    %edi, %esi
    shrl    $2, %esi
    cmpl    $3, %edi
    leal    0(,%rsi,4), %eax
    jbe .L8
    testl   %eax, %eax
    je  .L8
    vmovdqa .LC0(%rip), %xmm1
    xorl    %edx, %edx
    xorl    %ecx, %ecx
    .p2align 4,,10
    .p2align 3
.L6:
    addl    $1, %ecx
    vpmulld a(%rdx), %xmm1, %xmm0
    vmovdqa %xmm0, b(%rdx)
    addq    $16, %rdx
    cmpl    %esi, %ecx
    jb  .L6
    cmpl    %eax, %edi
    je  .L7
    .p2align 4,,10
    .p2align 3
.L9:
    movslq  %eax, %rdx
    addl    $1, %eax
    movl    a(,%rdx,4), %ecx
    addl    %ecx, %ecx
    cmpl    %eax, %edi
    movl    %ecx, b(,%rdx,4)
    jg  .L9
.L7:
    rep
    ret
.L8:
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    jmp .L9
    .cfi_endproc
```

Loops can be unrolled as well, it would just make for a longer code, which I do not want to paster here. You can trust me - compilers do unroll loops.

### Conclusion

Manual unrolling will do you no good.

Comment: This is overstating things, to put it mildly. Compilers certainly can and do unroll loops, and they can generate vectored code as well, that much is true. It's also true, however, that in some cases hand-unrolled loops beat current compilers (sometimes by a wide margin). Here's [one example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25578124/179910).

Comment: @JerryCoffin, you've hit a cornercase. In 2014, by the way. 2 generations of gcc compiler ago. In my experience any time spent on manual loop unrolling should be spent on otherwise. The cost-benefit will always be better.

Comment: That particular test was a couple of years ago. Last week I did something pretty similar with the pre-release of gcc 6, and got pretty similar results. The cost/benefit...well, without my unrolling, the code I was working on last week simply couldn't keep up with the required data rate, so the cost would have been to license a faster ARM core and design new hardware. I have a hard time believing that would be less expensive than the 15 minutes (or so) I spent unrolling the loop.

Comment: Like Jerry, I bristle at the general advice "trust your compiler, don't hand-optimize." I prefer to *hope* that the compiler will get it right, and then check to verify. On non-speed critical code, it does well enough. On critical code, you might find yourself pleasantly surprised, or you might be disappointed and need to spend 15 minutes to an hour rolling up your sleeves and hand-optimizing. Admonishing people never to do this is completely wrong. But at the same time, prematurely optimizing without looking to see what the compiler is doing is equally wrong.

Comment: In sum: This answer is good in this particular case, because you've actually checked to see what the compiler does. But don't overgeneralize your advice. It isn't the case that manual unrolling *never* does any good.